# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios.'

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

cuando quiero hacer un comando Oledbcommand select me tita este error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios.'

esto agarra datos de una base de datos de access.

adjunto  foto de base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
       int nped = Convert.ToInt32(txtnped.Text);

        bool idencontrado = false;
        panel_datos.Visible = false;

        if (txtnped.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Número de pedido");
        }

        conexion.Open();

        OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand();
        select.Connection = conexion;
        select.CommandText = "Select * From scann Where id= '" + nped + "'";
        OleDbDataReader lector = select.ExecuteReader();

        while (lector.Read())
        {
            idencontrado = true;
            cliente_print = lector["cliente"].ToString();
            fecha_print = lector["fecha"].ToString();
            pedido_print = lector["pedido"].ToString();
            precio_print = lector["precio"].ToString();
            n_pedido_print = lector["impreso"].ToString();
        }
        conexion.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendaria no concatener el valor en un string, si el campos es numerico incremental va sin comillas simples

```
string query = "Select * From scann Where id= @id";
OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand(query, conexion);
select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", nped);

OleDbDataReader lector = select.ExecuteReader();
```

Veras que uso el `Parameters.AddWithValue()` para asignar el valor en la consulta